# How to find latest 'n' files in a directory from cmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to get the latest 5 files in a directory.

This gave me the latest file:

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "*.yaml" /B /O:D') DO SET NewestFile=%%I
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please explain what you mean by latest, `most recently created`, `most recently accessed` and `most recently written`, are all available options within the `Dir` command. To see those options, `[/T[[:][C|A|W]]]`. You can open up a Command Prompt and enter `Dir /?`, whilst you're there you should also note that you can reverse the `sortorder` using                   `[/O[[:][-][D]]]`.

Comment: Do you want the paths/names of the 5 file to be echoed, or to be stored in environment variables? (Please [edit] your question instead of commenting!)

Answer (score 1):

The following example is intended to perform the task as laid out in your question and as implied by my advisory comment:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('"Set Newest[ 2>NUL"')Do Set "%%A="
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%A In (
    '"Dir /B/A:-D/O:-D/T:W "*.yaml" 2>NUL|FindStr /LINE ".yaml""'
)Do If %%A LEq 5 (Set "Newest[%%A]=%%B")Else GoTo :Next
:Next
Set Newest[ 2>NUL&&Pause
```

I have used the most recently written in the above example and the last line was included just to show you any variables set within the `For` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to get the five (5) newest files according to "last write time." Be sure to change the `-Path` directory to yours.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "delims=" %%f IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\src\t" -Filter '*.yaml' |" ^
        "Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending |" ^
        "Select-Object -First 5 |" ^
        "ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }"') DO (
    SET "NEWFILE=%%~f"
    ECHO Do something with "!NEWFILE!"
)
```